# Do you need a teleporter to use a Boarding Drone?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I recently found a Boarding Drone, but was wondering; do you need a teleporter to teleport the drone onto the enemy ship, or does it automatically spawn at a room in the enemy ship?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will automatically fire across to board the enemy ship.  Beware ships with defense drones, as they will shoot down a boarding drone just like it was a missile.  That's also a great way to defend yourself against ships that use boarding drones on you.

Comment: Boarding drones don't help defend your ship, Anti-Personnel Drones do.

Comment: @Robotnik: He's saying Defense Drones are a good defense against Boarding Drones.

Comment: @Ullallulloo - Oh ok, misread that

Comment: To clarify "Defense Drones are a good defense against Boarding Drones" *before they have landed on your ship*. After they land, the  Anti-Personnel Drones take over. :)